DBeaver - Set default Column Target Type for CSV Import data
I am trying to import a large number of CSV files as tables into DBeaver. With each CSV file, DBeaver seems to guess the column target type. Is there a way to stop this from happening? I want every column to be imported as a string. Is there a way to achieve this? 
